# Can someone help me with my tic tac toe logic

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

```
    private void chechWin_Loose_Draw()
    {
        if(_00.Text.Equals(_01.Text) && (_01.Text.Equals(_02.Text)))
        {
            if ((count & 1) == 0){

                richTextBox1.Text = "Winner: X";
            }
            else
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = "Winner: O";
            }
        }
    }
    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count++;
        chechTurn();
        printXorO(_00);
        _00.Enabled = false;
    }
```

I am trying to program a simple tic tac toe game but the code above doesn't affect the flaw of the program. I tried to put 3 X's and also 3 O's to 00 , 01, 02 squares but when all the squares have same text the rich text box doesnt Show the current situation. Thank you.

Comment: what is (count & 1)?

Comment: @Gino it is bitwise operator. If number and 1 equals 1 it is true otherwise false. Like modulo

Comment: You need to learn how to debug.  Start reading here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx

Comment: @Gino `(count & 1) == 0` means true if number is even.

Comment: The code can be different.  It's the problem that's a duplicate.

Comment: Is not the same. using the bitwise is much faster according to Wikipedia.

Comment: what do you mean by "_rich text box doesnt Show the current situation_". do you mean rich textbox doesn't show anything at all and is always blank?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary the rich text box normally shows the turn. But when I fill the top line with X's it doesnt change and shows "Turn: O"

Comment: check if `count` is correctly incrementing. may be count is not setting at all. probably its always 0.

Comment: Naming isn't part of your effort in trying to program a simple tic tac toe game is it?

Comment: I don't know why you're jumping to wikipedia optimizations when tic-tac-toe logic is tripping you up. Start by making it simple and readable (that includes to other people). After that, do what you like, but tackle one problem at a time. Have you tried breakpoints and stepping through while watching your variables? Which line is the issue? Does it even enter the if statement, how do you know?

Comment: also note that comparing strings by Equals is case sensitive. and textboxes must contain exact same thing. even extra space will make the comparison to return false. you can make comparison case insensitive by doing `Text.Equals(Text2 , StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: @Shen I tried debugging and where is the complicated part? If it is count & 1, it is not very complicated, and actually pretty common.

Comment: If it's not complicated, then you should be telling us the issue, but here we are. That's my point. Code it in assembly if you care so much about optimizing a tic tac toe program...

Comment: Add a breakpoint to every line in this function. Add all variables within the functions scope to a watchlist (right click -> add to watchlist). Step through each line and observe. What behaviour was unexpected?

Comment: When it comes to naming I mean giving understandable, meaningful names like labelEndTurn instead of label3 and textBoxWinner instead of richTextBox1 for example. Like `count`: what does it count? It might be obvious for you as the author but not to anyone else. It is a good habit to apply proper naming even on (very) small projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my mistake, and I am really sorry about taking your time. I noticed that I didn't place my function to the event handler.

```
private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count++;
        chechTurn();
        printXorO(_01);
        checkWin_Loose_Draw();// here ...
        _01.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to be sorry. Just look at the help section of this site to learn how to ask questions that will get a positive response. We don't want to scare you away just that you ask questions that are relevant and answerable.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Keep comin' back!